# Вопрос к профи JavaScript о жизнеспособности кода select

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Вопрос к профи JavaScript о жизнеспособности кода.

Пользовательский select. полная свобода над тем что и куда вставлять.

**Просьба дать обратную связь насколько всё плохо или хорошо).**

```js
const nameSelect = "quiz";
const EL = document.querySelector("." + nameSelect + "-select");

const EL_TOGGLE = EL.querySelector("." + nameSelect + "-select__toggle");
const EL_TOGGLE_ALL_EL = EL_TOGGLE.querySelectorAll("*");
const EL_TOGGLE_SELECTED_OPTION = EL_TOGGLE.querySelector("." + nameSelect + "-select__toggle-selected");

const EL_OPTIONS = EL.querySelector("." + nameSelect + "-select__options");
const EL_OPTION = EL_OPTIONS.querySelectorAll("." + nameSelect + "-select__option");


const EL_DROPDOWN = EL.querySelector("." + nameSelect + "-select__dropdown");
let selectOptionValue = "";
let selectOptionIndex = 0;

// Показ скрытие списка
function showHide() {
  EL_DROPDOWN.style.display === "block" ?
    (EL_DROPDOWN.style.display = "none") :
    (EL_DROPDOWN.style.display = "block");
}

// Добавляет событие открытия на все дочерние элементы внутри toggle
// Добавляем атрибут select__toggle_children ко всем дочерним элементам
EL_TOGGLE.addEventListener("click", showHide);
EL_TOGGLE_ALL_EL.forEach(function(event) {
  event.addEventListener("click", showHide);
  event.setAttribute("select__toggle_children", "1");
});

// Скрывает список с опциями
// Не скрывает список, если кликаем по дочерним элементам
// selectToggle проверяет есть ли у EL_TOGGLE дочерние элементы
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const selectToggle = event.target.getAttribute("select__toggle_children");
  if (event.target != EL_TOGGLE && 1 != selectToggle) {
    EL_DROPDOWN.style.display = "none";
  }
});

// Выбор элементов из списка 
EL_OPTIONS.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Удалить класс у всех li элементов внутри EL_OPTIONS
  EL_OPTION.forEach(function(option, index) {
    option.classList.remove(nameSelect + "-select__option-selected");
    option.setAttribute("data-index", index);
  });

  // Добавить класс elect__option_selected к выбранному элементу
  event.target.classList.add(nameSelect + "-select__option-selected");
  selectOptionValue = event.target.getAttribute("data-value");
  selectOptionIndex = event.target.getAttribute("data-index");

  // Поднимаем в верх выбранный элемент списка
  EL_OPTIONS.insertBefore(event.target, EL_OPTIONS.firstChild);

  // Добавить в  выбранный элемент списка текст.
  EL_TOGGLE_SELECTED_OPTION.innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
.quiz-select {
  position: relative;
}

.quiz-select__toggle {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  border: 1px solid #383838;
  border-radius: 16px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 16px;
}

.quiz-select__toggle::after {
  width: 0.75rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"%3E%3Cpath d="M97.625 25.3l-4.813-4.89c-1.668-1.606-3.616-2.41-5.84-2.41-2.27 0-4.194.804-5.777 2.41L50 52.087 18.806 20.412C17.223 18.805 15.298 18 13.03 18c-2.225 0-4.172.804-5.84 2.41l-4.75 4.89C.813 26.95 0 28.927 0 31.23c0 2.346.814 4.301 2.439 5.865l41.784 42.428C45.764 81.174 47.689 82 50 82c2.268 0 4.215-.826 5.84-2.476l41.784-42.428c1.584-1.608 2.376-3.563 2.376-5.865 0-2.26-.792-4.236-2.375-5.932z"/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
  background-size: cover;
  content: "";
}

.quiz-select__toggle div p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
}

.quiz-select__toggle div p:first-child {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #9b9b9b;
}

.quiz-select__dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 6px;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.quiz-select__options {
  max-height: 160px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.quiz-select__option {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}

.quiz-select__option::before {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-image: url("../img/checked.png");
  background-size: cover;
  content: "";
}

.quiz-select__option-selected {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 52px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #383838;
}

.quiz-select__option-selected::before {
  background-position-x: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.quiz-select__option:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s background-color ease-in-out;
}


/* Работает в Firefox */

* {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: #d8d8d8;
}


/* Работает в Chrome, Edge и Safari */

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz-select">
  <button type="button" class="quiz-select__toggle">
                <div>
                <p>Машина</p>
                <p class="quiz-select__toggle-selected">Выберите из списка</p>
              </div>
              </button>
  <div class="quiz-select__dropdown">
    <ul class="quiz-select__options">
      <li class="quiz-select__option  quiz-select__option-selected" data-value="volkswagen" data-index="">Volkswagen</li>
      <li class="quiz-select__option" data-value="ford" data-index="">Ford</li>
      <li class="quiz-select__option" data-value="toyota" data-index="">Toyota</li>
      <li class="quiz-select__option" data-value="ford" data-index="">Ford</li>
      <li class="quiz-select__option" data-value="toyota" data-index="">Toyota</li>
      <li class="quiz-select__option" data-value="ford" data-index="">Ford</li>
      <li class="quiz-select__option" data-value="toyota" data-index="">Toyota</li>
      <li class="quiz-select__option" data-value="ford" data-index="">Ford</li>
      <li class="quiz-select__option" data-value="toyota" data-index="">Toyota</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить еще один свой селект, работает?)

Comment: Как мне выбрать элемент без мышки? Что если опций в селекте 100 штук, как быстро перейти на нужную. Все это работает без проблем в нативном селекте.

Comment: По поводу добавить 2-ой  3-й и т.д. согласен, пока думаю.
По выбору элемента не мышкой а клавой не думал даже, интересно.

Comment: Я бы ничего этого не делал, тех задание было, надо было написать на чистом html, css, js.